# Kegging an 11% stout

Tags: kegging, flavor, stout, oak, bourbon

Stupid question...but I am making an 11% stout with bourbon oak added.  I have never kegged anything higher than a 7% so not sure what to expect.

Will the higher abv allow it to last longer in the keg to drink all Winter?  Should I add more bourbon so the taste doesn't dissipate?  Anything else I should think about?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kegged beer should last almost as long as bottled beer if sanitation and gas pressures are properly maintained. I don't think you need to do anything different because you are kegging it. The high ABV should allow you to store it in a keg for many months if not years.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking forward to having a heavy one on tap for when I have to shovel the snow